# What is the best and easy way to do memory profiling?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)
>   [What's the best tool to track a process's memory usage over a long period of time in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97590/whats-the-best-tool-to-track-a-processs-memory-usage-over-a-long-period-of-tim)

What is the best and easy way to do memory profiling and identifying a potential memory leak in a simple c# console project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best tool to track a process's memory usage over a long period of time in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97590/whats-the-best-tool-to-track-a-processs-memory-usage-over-a-long-period-of-tim) or [Best way to track down a memory leak (C#) only visible on one customer's box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150805/best-way-to-track-down-a-memory-leak-c-only-visible-on-one-customers-box)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend these two:

[Red Gate Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) (14 day free trial)

[JetBrains DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/?gclid=CJ_C9Y-TlKwCFYEZ4QodhnXbnA) (10 day free trial)

I've been pleased in the past with both - for a range of interesting profiling tasks.

Answer (score 0):

How about [How To: Use CLR Profiler from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx)?